# Adjusting brightness and contrast on an ASUS monitor?

Tags: display, display-settings

I feel really silly having to ask this but I can't figure out how to use the brightness and contrast buttons on my [ASUS VS247H monitor](http://www.asus.com/Monitors_Projectors/VS247H/overview/). The buttons are clearly labeled but they don't seem to do anything. I've tried a quick press, long press, and in different "mode" contexts. The on screen setup menu shows the values for brightness and contrast, but they're always grayed out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just had this problem and discovered it was because I had "eco" mode turned on (under system setup).

Comment: I had the same issue on my ASUS PB278 and turning ECO Mode OFF in System Setup solved the problem for me as well and I was then able to adjust brightness and contrast settings for all Splendid profiles.

Comment: 2021 and I swore I wouldn't have to google it. I did. Who designs their UIs? Jesus.

Answer (score 4):

Since this came up as a first page result for my search for "asus tuf gaming vg289 brightness",

I found in my case it was because Mac OS had defaulted "High Dynamic Range" to enabled. If you disable that, then you can configure all the brightness settings with monitor's buttons.

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 3.5 years, and I have a different Asus monitor, but to fix this I disabled Game mode and Eco mode in the system setup, and changed the splendid mode to standard. After that I was able to adjust brightness and contrast separately.

Comment: A bit unrelated question to the post (sorry for this): When you control the brightness setting on your Asus monitor, does it actually make the amount of light more/less intense (dimming the backlight)? Or does it just make the image kind of more/less gray like on regular TVs? (Again sorry for the offtopic, but I am wanting to buy one and have no way to verify this!)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by doing this in the screen menu:

System setup > All Reset > Yes

I just got this screen, but it appears it locks all the modes in the 'splendid' tab...

Answer (score 0):

For a Asus ProArt Monitor the solution is as follows in 2021:

> ProArt monitors can select different Preset modes in the OSD menu
> according to needs,
>
> sRGB mode is made according to the standard provided by the sRGB
> definition, so it cannot adjust the color settings, including the
> brightness.
>
> If you want to set the monitor to sRGB color gamut, but you want to
> adjust the brightness or other color settings according to your
> preferences,
>
> You can select Rec.709 mode and modify it. The color display of this
> mode is the same as that of sRGB mode, but it can be adjusted various
> color settings.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1043885